# Fetching images gallery of 1 product in Commerce.js

Tags: commerce.js

Please, tell me how can i fetch all images of 1 individual product in commerce js. Cant find anything in documentation.

So, i have a single product, but instead of uploading just 1 photo, I uploaded 20.
I can only get the very first photo to be displayed. Is there a way to list all 20? There must be a way since commercejs allows more than 1 photo to be uploaded there [thats images of my product][1]

Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0eZA.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `assets` list on a product object, see docs here: https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#get-product. You could filter them by `is_image` if you have other assets attached that aren't images.

```
const productImages = product.assets.filter((asset) => asset.is_image)
```

The `image` object only returns the main image, whereas `assets` will return the rest.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let u know! Are u good at commerce js? I might have another question re image gallery. How would u create a grid image gallery? Not all libraries work in react 18